# DC-DC Regulator/Converter to Power Robot and Laptop

Tags: power, dc

I have a small form factor Lenovo IdeaCentre PC that I would like to use as the primary controller for a large scale tanked robot. I've ironed out the accessory connections using usb->server controllers and usb->motor controllers. However I am not certain how best to power the actual PC using LIPO batteries. The power supply/brick that shipped with the PC is a standard AC->DC 19v 3.42amp power supply. I'd like to power the robot and pc using ThunderPower lipo's, what type of regulator/converter is available for purchase? Or am I completely wrong in what I need? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What voltage are you getting from the Li cells?

Comment: In addition, is there a DC to DC converter already inside the PC?  If running on battery, it might make sense to jump past that with the DC to DC solution.  This will be more efficient than boosting up to 19 and letting it convert back down a second time.

Comment: You could probably get away with a 5S LiPo pack, but you would be running at 21V at maximum, and at 3.7V/cell, about 18.5V (which may be too low.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need a regulator/converter that produces as a 19V output and can provide at least 3.42A.

[This one](http://www.batteryspace.com/dc-dcregulatormodulefrom222v-259vdcto19v4ampmax.aspx) should work provided you have enough batteries to give it a proper input.

Comment: Couldn't they put at least cheap reverse polarity protection diodes?